# Is Blinkroot a source of light?

Tags: terraria

On Terraria, the requirements for an NPC living space are light, a chair and a table. Can Blinkroot be a source of light?

Comment: I would assume not... there are other light-producing items that don't count (i.e., Disco Ball, Furnace)

Answer (score 7):

**No**, A Blinkroot cannot be used as a light source.

Comment: @Qwertyfizzle: If this answers your question, you should **accept** it by clicking the check mark near the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly not, I had in mind to build/grow a tree house for the dryad but had to resort to green torches for lighting.